# with trackId in AVMutableVideoComposition

Tags: ios, swift

so I am working on this video editor project and I faced a problem with getting the trackID 
I searched every where I know and all I can found was some objective-c code which I couldn't transform it to swift

I get the error in this line :

```
layer?.trackID = videoAsset?.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
```

The Error is

> Cannot assign to the result of this expression

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class VideoMakerViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate {
    var videoAsset: AVAsset? = nil
    var videoEditor: AVMutableVideoComposition? = nil
    var videoEditorInstroctions: AVVideoCompositionInstruction? = nil
    var layer: AVVideoCompositionLayerInstruction? = nil


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBAction func chooseVideo(sender: AnyObject) {
        var videoPicker = UIImagePickerController()
        videoPicker.delegate = self
        videoPicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        videoPicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie]
        videoPicker.allowsEditing = false
        presentViewController(videoPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
        let videoName = url.path!.lastPathComponent
        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String
        let localPath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(videoName)
        println(videoName)
        videoAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: url, options: nil)

        videoEditorInstroctions?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor

        layer?.trackID = videoAsset?.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        videoEditor = AVMutableVideoComposition(propertiesOfAsset: videoAsset)
        videoEditor?.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(60, 30)
        videoEditor?.renderSize = CGSize(width: 600, height: 1000)
        videoEditor?.renderScale = Float(1)

        println(videoAsset?.duration)    
    }
}
```

Comment: "I get the error" - what error?

Comment: Cannot assign to the result of this expression
Sorry I just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: `trackID` is read-only. To be able to assign anything to it, you have to use [`AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction) instead of `AVVideoCompositionLayerInstruction`.

Second: [`tracksWithMediaType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAsset/tracksWithMediaType:) returns

> An array of [`AVAssetTrack`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetTrack_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAssetTrack) objects of the asset that present media of mediaType.

while `trackID` is of type [`CMPersistentTrackID`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CoreMedia_DataTypes/). Therefore you cannot assign one to the other.

You can however / have to retrieve the ID your are looking for from any of the objects in the returned array:

```
layer?.trackID = (videoAsset?.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].trackID)!
```

or

```
layer?.trackID = videoAsset!.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].trackID
```

Comment: the error is gone but the trackID is nil !
I got an array with two tracks 
but the layer?.trackID get nil  !

Comment: @codeHorizons Have you tried debugging it?  taking a look what `videoAsset` is, what `videoAsset?.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)` is and what `(videoAsset?.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].trackID)!` is? I have no file to test that right now, but judging from the log the track should actually be set - if your layer is non-nil of course, is it?

Comment: there is one element this time but the result is the same !Optional([<AVAssetTrack: 0x1740061d0, trackID = 1, mediaType = vide>])    
nil

Comment: @codeHorizons What are you logging to produce that output? Try logging every step - if something does not work as intended, log the shit out of it :P

Comment: I've tried to debug but all the values are fine ! the only problem is with that property (trackID)

Comment: @codeHorizons For my demo projects everything works as expected. I'll ask again: is your `layer` initialized? Your code shows **no code creating a instance for `layer`**

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to work with initializers , but I assigned it to nil then tried to assign an AVAsset to it when the user chose the video but that didn't work , so what can I do to initialize it ? and is there any good tutorial about initializers ? sorry I took a lot of your  time

Comment: @codeHorizons Well, you are using it, I have no idea for what though. You can just create one by writing `layer = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction()`.

Comment: So all what I had to do is creating an empty object ! sorry for the trouble luk , That worked ! Thank you very much